# Where will partitions be distributed after RDD.zip() operation

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose we have a RDD `rddBefore` which turns into `rddAfter` after some map operations. One partition `partitionBefore` in `rddBefore` corresponds to `partitionAfter` in `rddAfter`.

Since spark may downgrade locality during calculation, `partitionBefore` and `partitionAfter` can be distributed on different machine, say `m1` and `m2`.

After `rddBefore.zip(rddAfter)`, which machine will `(partitionBefore, partitionAfter)` be distributed onto?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible cases:

- If `preferredLocations` for both parents overlap these locations will be used as preferred for the child.
- Otherwise union of the `preferredLocations` is used (no parent is preferred).